# How can I run Windows on Ubuntu without vt-x?

Tags: windows, virtualization

I've got an Intel Atom processor that has no vt-x. How can I run Windows 7 or 8 on my computer without vt-x (guest OS, maybe ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is still true of the current version of VMware Player, but version 4.0 doesn't require vt-x, unless you are running a 64bit guest OS.

Sources:
http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware_player40.pdf

You can download VMware Player here:
https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0

To install vmware player type in terminal: `sudo cd /locationyousavedbundle/nameoffile.bundle`